how to break out of a nested for loop and each loop in cypress
I am writing a test scenario where I have a .each() inside a for-loop and I would like to break out of .each() first and then for-loop once the condition is met however it seems like break cannot terminate .each() loop . I looked into StackOverFlow and noticed .each() can be terminated by every and return false but then the Cypress starts returning error messages.
This is the code I put together:
var isFalse = false
    for(var i = 0; i < 38; i++)
    {
        console.log(i)
        cy.get('tbody').eq(4).find('tr').each( rows =>
        {
            const exchnageNameText = rows.find('td').eq(1).children('div').children('a').children('div').text().trim()
            console.log(exchnageNameText)
            if(exchnageNameText == 'Kraken')
            {
                console.log(exchnageNameText+' found')
                isFalse = true                
            }
        }).then(()=>
        {
            console.log(isFalse)
            if(isFalse)
            {
                console.log('The token Tron is listed on Kraken. Happy trading!')
                // break
            }
            else
            {
                cy.wait(1000)
                cy.xpath('//*[@aria-label="next"]').click()     
            }  
        })
        if(isFalse)
        {
            //break
        }
    }    

I need to terminate .each() loop and for-loop where I commented in the code by "break" however it doesn't work when I replaced the first break by  return false
this is the web link to where the code performs: https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/tron
Could someone please look into the code and advise how I could break at the two commented lines?
Thanks,

You don't need the for loop, since you don't use it. Unless you intend just to repeat the test 30 times!

I have 38 pages and thebfor loop has to go through each of those pages. I placed for loop in the code to go through 38 pages and the each loop to check each of those 10 listed elements. I thought I need to use a nested loop

Nothing changes inside the loop, it's a false premise. There is no going to a "page" whatever that is.. Are you confusing "page" with table rows?
